# Bash script detect memory leaks of C++ programs

Tags: c++, bash, address-sanitizer

I'm writing a bash script that times some C++ programs compiled using `g++` with `-fsanitize=address`. Is there any way to detect whether any memory leaks occurred (from the script)?

Basically I want the aggregate times of those executions that did not leak and disregard those that did.

Comment: could run them in valgrind with `--error-exitcode` flag, but performance would be abysmal. If that's for  functional q/a and programs aren't real-time, maybe that's appropriate

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie thanks, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to detect whether any memory leaks occurred (from the script)?

You can look at the process exit code.

Address Sanitizer will force the program to exit with error code if leaks are detected. This assumes that the program itself correctly exits with error code 0.

> Basically I want the aggregate times of those executions that did not leak and disregard those that did.

Measuring time of an instrumented program is *pointless*.